# Proofs in coordinate geometry

Tags: geometry

Given a parallelogram RSTU in a coordinate plane, where:

- R = (b,c)
- S = (a + b, c)
- T = (a, 0)
- U = (0,0)

the statement
$ \sqrt{(b - 0)^2 + (c - 0)^2} = \sqrt{(b +a - a)^2 + (c-0)^2}$
would be used to prove...what?

I thought it would be used to prove that opposite sides were congruent, since when *not* simplified they both represent the $x\_coord + y\_coord$ of one point minus the $x\_coord + y\_coord$ of the point underneath it.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The formula they are using is euclidean distance.It is used to find out distance between two points.$A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$ are points then distance between these two points are

$AB=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$

and you are  correct in your last statement.

So in this question since this is a  parallelogram there are RS=UT and UR=TS and they apply euclidean formula on UR=TS.
this will helpful 
http://planetmath.org/euclideandistance