# Is it a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

I have quadrilateral $ABCD$ with vertices $A(-4,-1), B(0,0), C(1,4)$ and $D(-3,3)$. It *looks* like a parallelogram when I draw it, but how can I make sure?

I tried measuring the sides but that didn't seem very scientific. Is there a formula or something? Is it a parallelogram?

Comment: you can calculate the side lengths using Pythagorus' theorem

Answer (score 4):

Fix one point, say $B$. And calculate the $2$ vectors $\overrightarrow{BA}, \overrightarrow{BC}$. Then verify that $\overrightarrow{BA} + \overrightarrow{BC} = \overrightarrow{BD}$ where $A,C , D$ are the others points.

Basically you are checking that the parallelogram's rule holds so you basically are drawing a parallelogram with the two vectors $\overrightarrow{ BA}, \overrightarrow{BC}$ and their respective translate

NB thanks to @dfeuer that reminds the importance of checking linear independence of the vectors $\overrightarrow{BA}, \overrightarrow{BC}$ otherwise all statements obviously fall.

Comment: $+1$ to this for being the only answer so far that does not require checking several cases. The only missing piece is that you have to check that $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Completely agree, let me add this to the answer

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to verify that $\vec{AB}=(4,1)=\vec{DC}$.

Answer (score 0):

check if there are $AB=CD$ and $AD=BC$. To find these length use Euler formula check my answer in this link [Proofs in coordinate geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405907/proofs-in-coordinate-geometry/405915#405915)